# Advantage of Fourier transform on $\mathbb{Z}_N$

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

I ran into the following phylosophical question when I was working out Roth's Theorem:

Let $A$ be a subset of $\{1,2,\dots, N\}$. We can associate $A$ as a subset of cyclic additive group $\mathbb{Z}_N$ because we have at our disposal Fourier transform of $f:\mathbb{Z}_N\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $$\hat{f}(m):=N^{-1}\sum \limits_{x\in \mathbb{Z}_N}f(x)e\left(-\frac{xm}{N}\right), \text{where} \ e(x):=e^{2\pi i x}.$$ But in Roth's theorem we consider $f$ as a characteristic function of $A$, i.e. $f=\chi_A$.

Why we cannot apply Fourier transform directly to the set $\{1,2,\dots, N\}$, but not to the group $\mathbb{Z}_N$?
Maybe the set $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ has poor nature comparing to the group $\mathbb{Z}_N$?

Maybe this question sounds pointless, but would be thankful if somebody can give clear and persuasive answer!

Comment: $\{1,\dots,N\}$ is not a group.

Comment: @Wojowu, Yes I know that fact! Why we cannot extend discrete Fourier transform to a set $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, this is a matter of convenience - we could've done Fourier transform on $\{1,\dots,N\}$, but it would introduce certain technical details, for example, when defining convolution, we consider a sum of $f(y)g(x-y)$. If $y\geq x$, then we somehow have to "wrap around" to get back into $\{1,\dots,N\}$, while in $\mathbb Z_N$, this is immediate.

Comment: @Wojowu, If $y>x$ then $x-y<0$ and the element $x-y$ does not belong to our set however if we consider the group it belongs. You mean that? Good answer.